# How to find elements by id in ShadowDOM?

Tags: javascript, angular, shadow-dom

How can i get a reference to an element in an Angular Component with it's encapsulation set to ShadowDOM?

```
const element = document.getElementById(id);
```

for example, returns null

EDIT: Added html snippet

```html
<div *ngFor='let item of items' [attr.id]='item.key'>
.....
</div>
```

I need reference to each of the divs created.

Using a template variable works, but afaik you can not generate template variables dynamically.

E.g.

```html
<div #myTarget> ... </div>
```

works

Comment: Can you share what the HTML template looks like?

Comment: I've updated the question. I think that is the only relevant part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has nothing to do with the ShadowDOM at all, and you should not be selecting element by ID in Angular since that's an anti-pattern.  Instead, use [the `ViewChildren()` selector](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) in your TypeScript code!

```js
class SomeCmp implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChildren('myItem') items!: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(`I have ${this.items.length} items!`);
  }
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor='let item of items' #myItem>
.....
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using " encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom " in my component.ts

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that part... I've not used that feature very much.  Will the above code not work for that?

Comment: Is there any way to get an Element out of the QueryList by index? If yes, then i can make it work.

Comment: I've solved the issue by calling .toArray() on the queryList. Thanks for the suggestion!